# Frame.msg not working with db_decode from cantools

Tags: ros

I want to use the `can_msgs/Frame.msg` for decoding can messages using `db.decode_message(Frame.id, Frame.data)` but it is giving error

I want to try and write a new `Frame.msg` format but will it help?

```
def callback(Frame):
   rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", Frame.data)
   Temp = db.decode_message(Frame.id, Frame.data)
   temp.data = Temp
   pub.publish(temp)
```

I want to print the message in the dbc format that the cantools package helps decoding.

Error:

File "safa.py", line 42, in callback
    temp = db.decode_message(Frame.id, Frame.data)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cantools/database/can/database.py", line 379, in decode_message
    message = self._name_to_message[frame_id_or_name]
KeyError: 10

Comment: Just checking: you have (specially encoded) canbus data, published already on ros, as a bunch of can_msgs.Frame msgs. You want to receive the ros Frame msg, decode it, and I'm not sure what `temp` is (String/int/float, I assume), but you publish it. I'm not sure about your question > "I want to try and write a new Frame.msg format", isn't that the input?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely on point. I was thinking if I can edit the Frame.msg format and anything could work.

Comment: By 'edit', do you mean publish a new ros Frame msg with the data modified? The answer below addresses the error, but do you still have a design or implementation problem?

Comment: Please ignore what I said. If I send a candata over a rostopic or even as a stream though virtual can, will it get decoded using this code or not?

Comment: I have also tried the code that they provided on the github repository, but it is throwing the same error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I cannot attach a picture so here is the drive link. If you can help it will much appreciated. I have a lot of dependence on this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/15qZt4rWIV0mqb0rv6XmLRvCcixtN29Ey/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Stepping through your code, it uses a pre-made file, or set of definitions, to define a message called ExampleMessage, which it knows. You "encode" some data, line 17, into this format, and make a message out of it, line 18. But the message you receive in line 20 is not the same msg as the one you sent, because it throws an error in line 21: line 21 it tries to decode it, and cannot. The error is the same, the problem is you haven't defined what you wanted. If you just wanted to test out the encode/decode, without sending the msg you can both encode/decode it.

Comment: What is the actual point or goal of this? canbus is just an interface, you could get by just "encoding" and "decoding" the msgs yourself, saying bytes 0-1 are temperature, stored as an integer of this range, with this precision; ex hundreths of a degree Kelvin stored as an unsigned int_16.

Comment: Hi. I was able to get it done. I am using ROS for doing a project. I now juat stuck at publishing the rostopic because of class problem. 1.https://drive.google.com/file/d/16BxNmaMwd2eQYUyhFWDEbzKc9yKtSjnk/view?usp=drivesdk 2. https://drive.google.com/file/d/16CmHrfgWrLOOHBvX8bLp0ShabIGl4amw/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: You have a few problems. With regard to publishing a ros canbus msg, the commented out text does most of the work: you have to fill out a `Frame` with the id (int), data (array of 8 ints), and other data then publish that.

Comment: You also break one of the rules of ros: you declare 2 subscribers, to the same topic, with different message types. ROS topics are like (by analogy) global variables that you can write and read from: but they have a set, definitive type, which is the msg type. You declare both `Frame` and `String` as valid types for the same topic, which will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the cantools documentation for [db.decode_message](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/cantools/database/can/database.html#Database.decode_message), the KeyError is a bad description/error msg for the following.

`db` is a database (`class cantools.database.can.Database`), which stores all the weird encodings we may choose to use with cantools. To *decode* a message, it must already have an *encoding* stored within it, using one of the [`db.add_*`](https://cantools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cantools.database.can.Database) methods with the class.

Edit:
The definition of the [can_msgs/Frame](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/can_msgs/html/msg/Frame.html) is

```
std_msgs/Header header
uint32 id
bool is_rtr
bool is_extended
bool is_error
uint8 dlc
uint8[8] data
```

The data term requires an array/list of 8 uint8 values, not a string. Any CANbus data encoding must finish in this form.

Additionally, ROS provides an interface to the CANbus already: [socketcan_bridge](https://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_bridge) can be called in a launch file with your node at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can decode messages you should setup the database e.g by loading a dbc file:

```
   try:
        dbc_file_object = open(dbc_file, 'r')
    except IOError as e:
        rospy.loginfo('Unable to open file {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit(-1)

    self.db = cantools.db.load(dbc_file_object)
```